# Services running multiple times?

Tags: services, postgresql, debian-squeeze

I've installed a postgres db on my debian squeeze. There's a /etc/init.d/postresql to control the database. When I type `pstree -c`, I get two traces with postgresql. After `/etc/init.d/postgresl stop` I have still one trace left with postgresql. Where do I have to look for this issue? Is there an entry to start another postgresql at booting time? Where can I see this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have PostgreSQL installed from repository packages (e.g. [`postgresql-8.4`](http://packages.debian.org/pl/squeeze/postgresql-8.4)) this is perfectly possible if second cluster (let's say `test`) is set in `manual` mode:

```
cat /etc/postgresql/8.4/test/start.conf 
# Automatic startup configuration
# auto: automatically start/stop the cluster in the init script
# manual: do not start/stop in init scripts, but allow manual startup with
#         pg_ctlcluster
# disabled: do not allow manual startup with pg_ctlcluster (this can be easily
#           circumvented and is only meant to be a small protection for
#           accidents).

manual
```

You can check all registered clusters by `pg_lsclusters` command:

```
pg_lsclusters 
Version Cluster   Port Status Owner    Data directory                     Log file
8.4     main      5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main       /var/log/..
8.4     test      5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/test       /var/log/..
```

`pstree -c | grep postgres` result:

```
 |-postgres-+-postgres
 |          |-postgres
 |          |-postgres
 |          `-postgres
 |-postgres-+-postgres
 |          |-postgres
 |          |-postgres
 |          `-postgres
```

Manual mode (as opposite to **`auto`**) means that DB cluster **is not** handled by `/etc/init.d/postgresql` script, so after:

```
# /etc/init.d/postgresql stop
```

there is still one working server's instance:

```
pg_lsclusters 
Version Cluster   Port Status Owner    Data directory                     Log file
8.4     main      5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main       /var/log/..
8.4     test      5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/test       /var/log/..
```

and `pstree` returns remaining trace:

```
 |-postgres-+-postgres
 |          |-postgres
 |          |-postgres
 |          `-postgres
```

To shut down remaining instance explicitly use:

```
# pg_ctlcluster 8.4 test stop
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this interesting answer!! I'll check this next week at office and after that accept it :-)

Comment: Hi, I found the mistake with your manual: in the start.conf I can see "auto", so it is handled via init.d. Additionally, I started a postgres-server manually with /usr/lib/postgresql/8.4/bin/pg_ctl start... so there are many instances. Thank you!